# Design for many different updates to an object?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I am stuck in a design issue. 
My problem is that my solution to the problem is not clean. And code looks not nice.

This is what I want to do:

I have an plain class with properies storing values. 
The class values must validate to certain rules.

This is a simplified example:
A value class:

```
 class RecivedOrder
 {
     public AgreementId { get; set; }
     public OrderNr { get; set; }
     public Items { get; set; }
     public ProductId { get; set; }
     public ValidProductId { get; set; }         
     public InStock { get; set; }        
     public CustomerId { get; set; }     
     public NameOfCustomer { get; set; }         
     //..and many more properties..
 }
```

Validations/Update is done one the class like this:

```
 foreach (RecivedOrder o in RecivedDocument.Orders)
 {
    RecivedOrder.AgreementId = CheckIfValidAgreementId(o.AgreementId );
    RecivedOrder.ValidProductId = (bool)CheckIfValidProductId(o.ProductId);
    RecivedOrder.InStock = (bool)CheckProductIsInStock(o.ProductId);
    RecivedOrder.NameOfCustomer = GetNameOfCustomer(o.CustomerId);
    // ...and many more checks/validations....

    // The check methodes can do call to database..

 }
```

What I am looking for is a good design pattern for this.
Or a cleaner way to do this?

Best Regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, one pattern that I like to use for validation situations is to create a ValidationResults class, and have that be the return value of my Validate and Update functions on my object.  Something like this (super simple example):

```
public class ValidationResult
{
  public bool IsValid { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I would probably just define a Validate method on my ReceivedOrder class to return an instance of this class:

```
public ValidationResult Validate()
{
  var result = new ValidationResult();
  result.IsValid = true;

  if (!CheckIfValidAgreementId(this.AgreementId))
  {
    result.IsValid = false
    result.Message = "Invalid agreement ID";
  }
  else if (!CheckIfValidProductId(this.ProductId))
  {
    result.IsValid = false;
    result.IsValid = "Invalid product ID";
  }

  // ... and so on, with other validations

  return result;
}
```

Then I'd probably create an Update method on the object, which makes sure that the validation happens, and passes the result back up

```
public ValidationResult Update()
{
  var validationResult = this.Validate();

  if (validationResult.IsValid)
  {
    // ... your code to actually update the repository goes here
  }

  return validationResult;
}
```

Now, in the rest of your code, you can call Update on an individual object, and check the returned result.IsValid to verify that the update was successful.  If you need to update multiples, you can loop through them.

```
foreach (ReceivedOrder o in RecivedDocument.Orders)
{
  var result = o.Update();

  if (!result.IsValid)
    MessageBox.Show("failed to update order: " + result.Message); // or however you need to handle this
}
```

alternatively, you can call Validate yourself before calling Update, if that fits your use case better

```
foreach (ReceivedOrder o in RecivedDocument.Orders)
{
  var result = o.Validate();

  if (!result.IsValid)
    MessageBox.Show("validation failed: " + result.Message);
  else
    o.Update();
}
```

Comment: I think I use your suggestion here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fully implement your properties with private vars and get/set implementations.  Then you can do the check inside the set method.  For example:

```
private object _agreementId;
public object AgreementId 
{ 
    get { return _agreementId; } 
    set 
    { 
        if( !CheckIfValidAgreementId(value)) 
            throw new ArgumentException(); 
        _agreementId = value; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may code your application as follow:

```
foreach (RecivedOrder o in RecivedDocument.Orders) 
{
  if (!ReciveOrder.Check()) 
  {
     ... // Display order content on console
         // Then show errors:
     for (int i=0;i<Errors.Count;i++) Console.Writeline(Errors[i]) ;
  } 

class RecivedOrder
 {
   // your properties
   internal List<String> Errors = null ;

   internal bool Check()
   {
     Errors = new List<String>() ;
     CheckAgreementId() ;
     CheckProductId() ;
     ... // other checks
     return Errors.Count==0 ;
   }

   internal void CheckAgreementId()
   {
     bool IdOk = AgreementId>=0 ;
     ... // more controls on AgreementId
     if (!IdOk) Errors.Add("Invalid AgreementId="+AgreementId) ;   
   }

    internal void CheckProductId()
   {
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to define the purpose of a class when I'm designing objects.  For example is this an object that represents a database entity or an object to simply store data between points (i.e. DTO) or an object who's properties must adhere to some rules (i.e. Model) or something else like a business object that also has some behavior.

It appears yours may fall into the Model category.  Along with the answers provided here, you might also consider solutions such as

- [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Data Annotation Customization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx)
- Custom libraries like [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation)

Comment: That FluentValidation librarie looks nice. Thanks!